# Access Java anonymous object properties

Tags: java, android

I am relatively new to Java programming, i am trying to access an anonymous objects properties, this is my object:

```
Object tomorowWeekday = convertedTimeForAndroid(openHours, tomorrow);
```

Inspected via the debugger, it looks as this:
[image]

I need to access the key value pair "to" and "from", there is no method such as `tomorrowWeekday.get("from")`.

How would I access these values in an anonymous object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change to

```
JSONObject tomorowWeekday = convertedTimeForAndroid(openHours, tomorrow);
```

You're currently setting the declared type to `Object`. That means that you can't see any methods other than ones exposed by `Object`, even though the actual type is `JSONObject`. Make the declared type the same as the actual type and you'll be able to see all the methods you need.

Because `JSONObject` is a subclass of `Object` (as indeed every class is), your current code is legal, but it means you abstract away any functionality that isn't present in `Object`. This is sometimes a useful trick, but not one to employ unless you know why you're doing it.

(As a side note, the word *anonymous* is not quite appropriate here. It isn't anonymous: its name is `tomorrowWeekday`.)

Answer (score 0):

The fields and methods you can access on an object depend on the type of the variable that you use to it. In your code above, you are using a variable `Object` type, which does not have any knowledge of your `nameValuePairs` attribute. You'll need to change the type of your reference to something more representative of your actual object. Your debugger is saying that `nameValuePairs` is of type `JSONObject` so if you reference with a `JSONObject` variable, you'll be able to access it using the api specified here: http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html